# Comparing time hh:mm format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I changed my strings to 24hr format, but why are the times not comparing what am i doing wrong?

```
function getTwentyFourHourTime(amPmString) { 
    var d = new Date("1/1/2013 " + amPmString); 
    return d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes(); 
}

var inputStart = "6:00 AM";
var inputEnd = "10:00 PM";

var startDay = getTwentyFourHourTime(inputStart); 
var endDay = getTwentyFourHourTime(inputEnd); 


if(startDay < endDay){
alert("works!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are comparing Strings. When you do `return d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes();` It returns a string  and `"6:0"` is greatter than `"22:0"`.If you return only `d` your code will work properly.

```
function getTwentyFourHourTime(amPmString) { 
    var d = new Date("1/1/2013 " + amPmString); 
    return d; 
}

var inputStart = "6:00 AM";
var inputEnd = "10:00 PM";

var startDay = getTwentyFourHourTime(inputStart); 
var endDay = getTwentyFourHourTime(inputEnd); 


if(startDay < endDay){
alert("works!");
}
```

Check my [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6ak04s89/)

Hope it Helps you.

Comment: Thank you! this fixed the problem.